# Associating error messages with tex input

Tags: errors

I'm compiling a paper that someone else started and I have to fix some error messages associated with text that I've never read before.  When I compile the paper sometimes it gets to an error and I have to figure out where that is in the paper and how to fix it.

The warning messages give some information about what causes the warning, for example:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `label1' on page \thepage  undefined on input line 74.
```

These have been helpful for me in figuring out where `pdflatex` is in processing the file because the error messages are typically thigns like:

```
[5]

! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
```

This is just an example of one the errors that I've gotten to and am trying to fix.  I can Google for the error message and try to understand what is causing it.  But my question is: **is there an easy way to know what causes an error message to occur in latex?**

Mostly I'd like to see something like the line number information that is provided for warnings, but for errors instead.  I don't know if that feature exists or not but I thought it might be worth asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The complete error message you get has the necessary information below it:

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 $\begin{array}{lrq}
```

You can see where LaTeX was and, in this case, the reason for the error should be clear. The error is in line 3 of the file currently input.

If you run the typesetting engine with the option `--file-line-error` (how you do this depends on your TeX distribution and editor/front-end) the error message becomes

```
./gabrierr.tex:3: LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 $\begin{array}{lrq}
```

so you can also see *what* file LaTeX is processing.

Some errors are more difficult to find, because they may be triggered by something that happened several lines above (a missing brace or a missing `$`). But in most cases the error location is quite precise.